# Get list of selected items in parallel coordinates graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I saw this beautiful example of a parallel coordinate graph and implemented it for my own data visualization webservice: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7586334

[image]

However, I need to get a list of the selected items and show it to the user. Like in this example if you brush for 4 cylinder cars only, I want to have a list of all car names that are now painted in the foreground.

I thought about a jquery selector on `g.foreground path` and query for all displayed items.
but then I need to code the information in the element.

Or is there even a d3.js built-in for that kind of functionality?

Comment: This is exactly what's happening in the `brush` function -- every `foreground` that is not selected is not displayed anymore. The ones that are still displayed denote the selected cars. You can get that information directly in the `brush` function or afterwards by selecting the foreground lines that are not hidden.

Comment: okay, i added now the `name` field as text to each `path` and then query for all active things in the brush function and put them into a list... is this the best practice?

Comment: Usually, you would simply access the data bound to those lines.